# Materialize switch

Tags: php, html, checkbox, materialize

Good day.

Trying to create a checkbox (materialize switch), which, if you change it, submits the form. The problem is, that it returns the value as `$_POST['statusValue']` ONLY if its originally not checked, if it is - returns null.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="switch"> 
<form method="post"> 
<label style="font-size: 10px"> 
Off 
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_id?>" name="statusValue" id="statusValue" onclick='this.form.submit()' <?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_status == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?» 
<span class="lever"></span> 
On 
</label> 
</form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I guess what you are trying to achieve in check if the checkbox on the HTML was checked or not by the user.

Below, I wrote you a simple code of how achieving that. After submitting the form the $statusValue variable will contain either "checked" or "not checked" depending on what the user did on the HTML page.

---

In your HTML (frontend):

```
<div class="switch"> 
<form method="post"> 
<label style="font-size: 10px"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="statusValue" onChange="this.form.submit()" />
<span class="lever"></span> 
</label> 
</form> 
</div>
```

---

In your php (backend):

```
<?php
isset($_POST['statusValue'])
$statusValue = "checked";
else
$statusValue = "not checked";
?>
```

---

If I misunderstood you, comment here so I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

In this html code I create a function that has two parameters id and status that will pass throught it.

```
<div class="switch">
  <form method="post"> 
    <label style="font-size: 10px"> 
     Off 
     <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_id?>" name="statusValue" id="statusValue" onclick="changeStatus('<?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_id ?>,'<?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_status ?>')" <?php echo $q->questionnaire->questionnaire_status == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?» 
   <span class="lever"></span> 
     On 
    </label> 
  </form> 
</div>
```

Invoking the function changeStatus using Ajax function and avoiding to refresh the page in that time, you press the switch.

```
<script>
   function changeStatus(id,status){
       if(habilitado==2) {
        var url = 'admin/funciones/desbloquearUsuario.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:{idUser:id},
        error:function(){
            alert("It coudn't be disabled");
           }
         });
     }else {
         var url = 'admin/funciones/bloquearUsuario.php';
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:url,
            data:{idUser:id},
            error:function(){
            alert("it couldn't be blocked");
            }
          });

          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For this php file desbloquear.php I unblock Users setting value 1

```
   require_once "../../funciones/conexion.php" ;
   conexion();
   $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
   $habilita = 'UPDATE public."USUARIO" SET "Habilitado"=\'1\' WHERE 
   "ID"=\''.$idUser.'\'';
   pg_query($habilita);
```

In your php code you can use this. Well in this case, in this php  file I block users with the value 2 in my BD

```
   <?php

   require_once "../../funciones/conexion.php";
   conexion();
   $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
   $deshabilita = 'UPDATE public."USUARIO" SET "Habilitado"=\'2\' WHERE 
   "ID"=\''.$idUser.'\'';
   pg_query($deshabilita);
```